# cake burns on bottom

Tags: baking

Why is my cake burning on the bottom and the top is not done.  I must not have the oven rack in the right place.  If I want the cake to bake less on the bottom, what position should the rack be in.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you please tell us a bit more? What kind of oven are you using? What kind of pans?

Comment: Bake with the cake pan on an "Air Bake" sheet.

Comment: also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/why-does-my-bread-burn-at-the-bottom-before-it-is-done/33449#33449 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/what-is-the-proper-oven-rack-height-position-for-baking-cakes-and-cookies?rq=1

Comment: Gas oven? Electric oven? Other oven heat source? Convection, not convection ...and where in the oven is the pan when it's burning the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

A sheet of aluminum foil under the pan can help prevent burning on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If your oven heats unevenly you can also bake you cake with can pan on a sheet pan that is doubled up as well.(two sheet pans stack on top of each other) This helps with the bottom of cake (if you don't own a glass pan) from turning too dark too fast. Of course, you should in fact bake the cake in the center of the oven at best.

Answer (score 0):

Moving it up should help. Also try a glass pan not a metal pan that will slow the heat transfer into the cake.